# Read from file to array of strings, C

Tags: c

I'm trying to write a function that read string from a file into an array of strings using fgets(), but I keep getting `zsh: segmentation fault` at runtime.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void read(FILE*, char[][31],int*,int);
void printAll(char[][31],int*);

int main(int argc, char** argv) {


    FILE *in = fopen("strings.dat", "r");
    char strarr[50][31];
    int items=0;

    read(in,strarr,&items,31);
    printAll(strarr,&items);

}

void read(FILE *in,char arr[][31],int *items,int len){
    int i = 0;
    char temp[31];
    while (fgets(temp, len, in) != NULL) {
        strcpy(arr[i], temp);
        i++;
        items++;
    }
}
void printAll(char arr[][31],int *items){
    for(int i = 0;i<*items;i++){
        printf("String %d: %s\n",i+1,arr[i]);
    }
}
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Have you used `valgirnd` or clang/gcc's address sanitizer?

Comment: Is is essential to know to content of `"strings.dat"`: How many lines and the maximum length of all lines.

Comment: Probably unrelated to the segmentation fault, but you want `(*items)++` inside the function (increasing the pointer itself does no good or harm).

Comment: `fopen` might fail and you don't check that. If `fopen` fails and you continue, all kind of strange things may happen including "segmentation fault"

Comment: [read(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html) is a POSIX function (called by `fgets`), so use another name e.g. `my_read`. Please read [*how to debug small programs*](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). If you compile with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/), use `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` to get warnings and debug info

Comment: You need to read a lot more about [parsing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing) and about [the C programming language](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c). Take inspiration from *existing* code on [github](https://github.com/) or [gitlab](https://gitlab.com/). Use [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) and [getline(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html). Specify on paper your expected input using [EBNF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Backus%E2%80%93Naur_form)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I think you commented the wrong question....Happend to me too a few times...

Comment: @alk im trying to read a data file which can cantain less or more than 50 strings and I just want to put the first 50 line into my string array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is almost correct.

Errors:

1. In the `read` function `items++` is wrong, this increments the *pointer* but you want to increment the variable pointed by the pointer, therefore you need `(*items)++` instead.
2. Depending on the platform `read` will conflict with the posix `read` function.

---

The program will fail under following conditions:

1. If the file `strings.dat` does not exist, `in` will be `NULL` and doing file operations on a NULL `FILE` pointer results in undefined behaviour which often manifests in a seg fault. This is probably what happens to you.
2. If the file contains more than 50 lines you will be overflowing `strarr` which also results in undefined behaviour
3. If lines in the file have more than 31 characters, lines will be truncated and/or split.

---

Bonus:

The temp variable is not necessary, you can read directly into the array:

Instead of this:

```
 char temp[31];
 while (fgets(temp, len, in) != NULL) {
    strcpy(arr[i], temp);
    ...
```

You can have this:

```
 while (fgets(arr[i], len, in) != NULL) {
    ...
```

---

Final code with corrections:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void read(FILE*, char[][31], int*, int);
void printAll(char[][31], int*);

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  FILE* in = fopen("strings.dat", "r");
  if (in == NULL)
  {
    printf("file does not exist\n");
    exit(1);
  }
  char strarr[50][31];
  int items = 0;

  read(in, strarr, &items, 31);
  printAll(strarr, &items);

}

void read(FILE* in, char arr[][31], int* items, int len) {
  int i = 0;
  while (fgets(arr[i], len, in) != NULL) {
    i++;
    (*items)++;
  }
}

void printAll(char arr[][31], int* items) {
  for (int i = 0; i < *items; i++) {
    printf("String %d: %s\n", i + 1, arr[i]);
  }
}
```

---

Alternative version of `read`

```
void read(FILE* in, char arr[][31], int* items, int len) {
  int i = 0;
  while (fgets(arr[i++], len, in) != NULL) {
    (*items)++;
  }
}
```

Even shorter:

```
void read(FILE* in, char arr[][31], int* items, int len) {
  for (int i = 0; fgets(arr[i], len, in) != NULL; i++)
    (*items)++;
}
```

Comment: `while (fgets(arr[i], len, in) != NULL) ` for this statement, do i need to increment the index or i will increase automatically?

Comment: Why should it be incremented automatically, you're incrementing it correctly with the `i++` statement.

Comment: can i use *item point to a number that store how many strings are read into array?

Comment: @AKu yes, that's exactly what you were trying to do, but you wrote `items++` instead of  `(*items)++;`